# Excel: Pasting "USD 12.50" data into a sheet -> can a custom number format treat this as a number ON PASTE ACTION?

Tags: excel, format

Helping a close friend at risk of losing her job; we spent hours this weekend where I tried to help her automate a recurring task.

1. She pastes (from some source I don't know) a table containing one field in particular that has to be managed. The values are:

"USD 12.50"   - for example - without the quotes

ISSUE: this column of values can't be summed/operated on, as it's not formatted as a number

2. She was using the MID function; I know there are some text operators that can handle this and all -- but I said we need to move beyond this, cause manually converting all these values each time, screwing with the column order (adding new ones just to extract the # value), etc. are a bit error-prone. I also showed her Flash Fill before, but that's not what I'm looking for.

**My bottom line question is this:**

Is it possible to have that column we KNOW the "USD 12.50" or "USD 49.99" text values are going to be inputted into (perhaps paste values is part of the answer) --> is it possible for it to STAY as a Custom Number field that is EXPECTING "USD " string + a float afterwards?

If you "dumb paste" into Excel, I'm guessing it wipes out the custom number format you might have pre-formatted?

(Last bonus request: I have been playing with this for at least an hour, but I cannot for the life of my figure out how to do that custom number format in the first place *AND* have the values across cells eligible for summing, min/max/etc. etc... man, I know a bit of RegEx but I am really struggling with custom number formats.)

Thanks in advance & sorry for the length.

Comment: Have you looked at text to columns?

Comment: From where these values are coming? If you copying and paste then try paste values.

Comment: Short answer: conditional formatting can't do that.  But it easily be done with VBA. Is that an option for you.?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the source, but all the numbers coming in are roughly the same format as `USD 123`, then you can

- paste the value into column A
- use the formula `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))`

This first `FIND`s the space between the currency and the number, and then using `RIGHT` returns the rest of the text.

This works okay for well formatted input, and allows you to repeat many times without using the text to columns wizard.

String manipulation in excel gets you a long way!

Comment: Ah, thanks! That's an elegant solution given the RIGHT() function could mess up depending on the length of the currency value... thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Select the Column,
Press [Ctrl]+[h] for search and replace,
Enter „USD “ wihout quotes in SEARCH,
Leave REPLACE empty,
Press [Replace All]